# Derivate of finite sum?

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble finding the derivative of the following finite sum:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \ln\frac{n-k}{n}$$

I get the following:

$$\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{n-2}+\ldots+\frac{-1}{n}+\frac{-1}{n}$$

I know the closed form is:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \ln\frac{n-k}{n} = 
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}n} \ln\frac{n!}{n^n} = 
\mathrm{polygamma}(n+1) - \ln(n) - 1$$

But I can't seem to figure out why it cannot be evaluated by taking the derivative of each term. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it because k is dependent of n, and so d/dn ln((n-k)/n) = (k(1-dk/dn))/(n(n-k)) and when evaluated at n=c, dk/dc is not defined?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your reasoning (in particular, the terms correspond to derivatives of $\ln(n-1)$, $\ln(n-2)$, ..., but the last two terms seem somewhat of out place. Perhaps you meant $+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{n-1}{n}$ as the last two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not differentiate the terms individually and then sum them, since the number of terms in the sum depends on the variable we  are differentiating with.

Comment: For a simple example, consider the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n 1$ and its derivative with respect to $n$. Going term-by-term, one ends up with sum of $n$ zeroes, doing it the correct way yields $1$, as expected.